# L3 programming: \text_titlecase only seems to map properly when sequence is explicitly declared

Tags: expl3, latex3, text, strings, sequence

I'm trying to perform the following conversion using the l3 interface:

`my_figure_title -> My Figure Title`

After some trial and error with sequences and strings, here's what I came up with:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \str_new:N \myStr
        \seq_new:N \mySequence
        \cs_new:Npn \myFunc #1 {\text_titlecase:nn {en} {#1}}

        \str_set:Nn \myStr {my_figure_title}
        \str_replace_all:Nnn \myStr {_} {,}
        \seq_set_from_clist:NN \mySequence \myStr
        
        \seq_map_function:NN \mySequence \myFunc
        \par
        \myStr % should show my,figure,title
        \par
        \seq_item:Nn \mySequence {3} % should show Title
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the result shows all letters capitalized.

[image]

This is confusing to me, because when I try `seq_map_function:NN` on a sequence where the comma delimited list is explicitly declared, it seems to work fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \myFunc #1 {\text_titlecase:nn {en} {#1}}
    
    \seq_new:N \mySequence
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \mySequence {my,figure,title}
    \seq_item:Nn \mySequence {3}
    \myFunc {bla}
    \seq_map_function:NN \mySequence \myFunc
    \ExplSyntaxOff


\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the l3str module (functions starting with `\str_`) is used for programmatic strings, the l3text module (functions starting with `\text_`) deal with formatted text as it appears in a document.

Since your code first passes the string to l3str functions it gets turned into a programmatic string and then is no longer supported by l3text.

Since you want to print the string in the end you actually want to use formatted and not programmatic strings, so you can fix your issue by storing it in a `tl` variable instead of a `str` variable (and using l3tl instead of l3str functions): (I additionally fixed the names to follow expl3 conventions)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \ExplSyntaxOn
        \tl_new:N \l_my_tl
        \seq_new:N \l_my_seq
        \cs_new:Npn \my_transform_to_titlecase:n #1 {\text_titlecase:nn {en} {#1}}

        \tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl {my_figure_title}
        \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_my_tl {_} {,}
        \seq_set_from_clist:NN \l_my_seq \l_my_tl
        
        \seq_map_function:NN \l_my_seq \my_transform_to_titlecase:n
        \par
        \tl_use:N \l_my_tl % should show my,figure,title
        \par
        \seq_item:Nn \l_my_seq {3} % should show title
    \ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Note: If `my_figure_title` comes from outside of the `\ExplSyntaxOn`/`\ExplSyntaxOff` block then you would additionally have to deal with the different catcode of `_`.

Comment: I see. So whenever I want to print something out to the final output I should use text strings (`l3tl`) and whenever I don't, I should use programmatic strings (`l3str`). That's very good to know. It so happens that `my_figure_title` will be coming from outside the `expl3` block.... Is that very difficult to deal with?

Comment: Also, what does fixing the names to follow the convention actually *do*? I'm realizing I can get by just fine without the convention...

Comment: @user32882 The naming convention makes it easier to read and follow the code and is a sign for code quality.

Answer (score 5):

Converting to strings is the wrong idea, because you want to keep the nature of the tokens as letters.

Besides, you're using wrong naming of variables and function. Also, functions that perform unexpandable operations, such as `\seq_set_split:Nnn`, should be protected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\converttotitle}{m}
  {
    \mymodule_title_convert:n { #1 }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_title_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_title_out_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nxn }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_title_convert:n
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nxn \l__mymodule_title_in_seq { \char_generate:nn { `\_ } { 8 } } { #1 }
    \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l__mymodule_title_out_seq \l__mymodule_title_in_seq
      {
        \text_titlecase:nn {en} {##1}
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__mymodule_title_out_seq { ~ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\converttotitle{my_figure_title}

\end{document}
```

A slight complication is splitting at the underscore, which is a letter in the `expl3` environment, but has a different category code in the normal text. You might use a different and category code agnostic method using regular expressions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\converttotitle}{m}
  {
    \mymodule_title_convert:n { #1 }
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mymodule_title_tl
\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_title_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_title_out_seq

\quark_new:N \q_mymodule_us

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mymodule_title_convert:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__mymodule_title_tl { #1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \_ } { \c{q_mymodule_us} } \l__mymodule_title_tl
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l__mymodule_title_in_seq { \q_mymodule_us } \l__mymodule_title_tl
    \seq_set_map_x:NNn \l__mymodule_title_out_seq \l__mymodule_title_in_seq
      {
        \text_titlecase:nn {en} {##1}
      }
    \seq_use:Nn \l__mymodule_title_out_seq { ~ }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\converttotitle{my_figure_title}

\end{document}
```

The underscores are replaced by a quark that's then used as the point to split at.

In either case you get

[image]

Comment: I honestly don't understand *why* you have to assign the default catcode of 8 back to the underscore character in your first example. If anything, I would have expected assigning it a catcode of 11 so that it can properly be processed in the `\ExplSyntax` block.

Comment: @user32882 I want it to have the standard category code it has in normal text, when you will call the command.

Comment: fair enough. I decided to start going with dashes `-` instead of underscores `_` whenever I can in LaTeX. I use underscores out of habit (code a lot in Python). Better kick that when I'm using LaTeX because underscores have non-11 catcode.